# What is the number of maximum concurrent connections for Sql CE 3.5?

Tags: sql-server-ce

as google does not deliver what i want to know, i try to ask stackoverflow :)
what is the number of max concurrent connections to a sql ce 3.5 database?
thanks
j.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the information you are looking for is the SQL Server Edition Comparison.

For standard Editions - [Compare Features](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/prodinfo/features/compare-features.mspx?PHPSESSID=0324345d45ef1bf1f764044e03584cd0)

For Compact Edition - [Compare Features](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/prodinfo/features/compare-features.mspx?PHPSESSID=0324345d45ef1bf1f764044e03584cd0)

**Edit**

Sorry, this [Word Document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/7/A47B7B0E-976D-4F49-B15D-F02ADE638EBE/Compact_Express_Comparison.doc) is most likely what you need.

**Edit again**

The answer is 256 concurrent connections for Compact, unlimited for express.  See table 1 in the linked word doc.

Comment: Am I missing something?  I don't see anything in that documentation that lists specifically the number of connections you can use.

Comment: Updated, it is in the word doc!

Answer (score 12):

SQL Server Compact 3.5 supports multiple connections up to the 256 connection limit.([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983341.aspx))

Answer (score 4):

I know that SQL CE 3.5 allows multiple concurrent connections from multiple processes (as opposed to earlier versions that allowed, but did not recommend, multiples from only one process). My *guess* is that it's resource limited, but I'm not certain.  I actually have a call in to the SQLCE team directly to find out if there is a count limit on this (I'll post back when I get a reply, likely later today, though with PDC ongoing, it might be longer).

That said, I question why you would need to know this.  How many connections are you trying to make?  You should have at least 2 - it's recommended to always maintain 1 connection, even if it's a dummy that's never used, to keep the connection cached for performance reasons - but I've never done any implementation that had more than maybe 4 or 5 at any given time.  If you have more than that, you might need to rethink your architecture, or the app is more likely a candidate for a full-blown server product.

**Update**

I finally heard back from the team and they confirmed from the source code that the number is 256. This is what they said:

"...since we are implementing it in C/C++, the counter starts from 0 and ends in 255.  These are the number of **parallel connections** and **not** total connections.  For every open, the counter goes up by 1 and for every close it goes down by 1.  If you have not closed, but just unreferenced close happens on Dispose."

Answer (score 0):

You can wait, when 200 + 57th SQL-Ce connection request arrives.

For more-
http://ourtech24.com/Programming/OT-182638/Wait-for-upcoming-request-when-SQL-CE-connection-limit-is-exceeded/