# Using SQL server Compact 3.5

Tags: sql-server

I wish to use SQL Server Compact 3.5 Databse with my application.  The application is going to be run over a network where the database has to handel more than 30 connections at a time.

Is it the right choice I made?

Thanks
Furqan

Comment: SQL Server Compact is primarily intended as a machine-local storage. If you have a network, use a server version of SQL Server - much better scalability and performance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240463/what-is-the-number-of-maximum-concurrent-connections-for-sql-ce-3-5).  Sql Sever Compact 3.5 can handle 256 connections at a time.