# Application to be run on a network (shared through a hub)

Tags: sql-server-ce, scaling

I have developed a Computer Based Examination application. I have designed the application so that when initialized by admin. client computers could take exam with their logins. I am using SQL Server Compact Edition.
I tested it with a small network (shared computers through a hub) It works well.

I am not so good at networking things. Can I used the same way when the client computers are more than 50? Is there any better alternative?

Thanks 
Furqan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application to be run on a network (shared through a hub)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183964/application-to-be-run-on-a-network-shared-through-a-hub)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide more information on how your application is written for a good answer.

One thing that will be relevant is that [SQL Server Compact Edition is limited to 256 concurrent connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240463/what-is-the-number-of-maximum-concurrent-connections-for-sql-ce-3-5), so you would need to move up to something like SQL Server Express if you had more than 256 client computers at once.